# redirect subfolder/index.php to subfolder/

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm trying to redirect any requests to `subfolder/index.php` to `subfolder/` and still display the contents of the subfolder's `index.php` file.  This isn't specific to just one subfolder so I need a general rule.  But note that some directories, such as `css/` and `images/` won't have an index.php file and I'd just want to deny access to them if the user tried to hit those specific directories.

At the moment, a request to `subfolder/index.php` goes to `subfolder/index/` (but does still actually show the contents of index.php).  This is due to the rule I have to replace .php extensions with a trailing slash (thanks to the other posts on this forum!)

So I think I'm just missing a rule that sits above my trailing slash rule.

So far I have this:

```
RewriteEngine On

# make all requests to the domain root show contents of index.php
DirectoryIndex index.php
#Permanently move requests to index.php to the domain root
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ / [NC,R=301,L]

#do not allow a directory listing
Options -Indexes


##**** INSERT RULE HERE TO DEAL WITH SUBFOLDER INDEX FILES****


## hide .php extension snippet

# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/ [R=301,L]

# add a trailing slash    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule . %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301]

# To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Any help would be much appreciated as I've been struggling with the htaccess file for a while and can't work out the answer.

Comment: Add this after `Options -Indexes`: `RewriteRule ^subfolder/$ subfolder/index.php [L]`

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply.  I've added tested this line but it doesn't appear to do anything.  Can you explain what it should be doing?  Also please note that I'm trying to achieve this for all subfolders, not specific ones.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comment out this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ / [NC,R=301,L]
```

And insert this rule in same place:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*/)index\.php$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301,NE]
```

Comment: Excellent - this works perfectly.  Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: anubhava - do you know how I could exclude a specific URL, such as https://www.example.com/blah/index.php so that it is exempt from getting any URL rewrite?

Comment: To skip add `RewriteRule ^blah/index\.php$ - [L,NC]` just below `RewriteEngine` line